# Why does robocopy fail this folder?

Tags: robocopy

I have this weird folder in my windows 10 system drive, this doesn't seem to be a junction point so I don't know what it is, please see picture.

I am trying to copy it with `robocopy` from an admin CLI from a WindowsPE off a Windows Installation Media USB stick, with the following command:

```
Robocopy c:\testHere2\ f:\backuptestHere2 /MIR /B /R:0 /NFL /NDL /XJ /NP /XA:o /MIN:1 /XA:S /log:f:\testHere2.txt
```

The errors I’m getting are:

```
NOTE : Security may not be copied - Destination might not support persistent ACLs.
2021/08/14 08:39:32 ERROR 0 (0x00000000) Copying File c:\testHere2\a.txt
The operation completed successfully.
2021/08/14 08:39:32 ERROR 0 (0x00000000) Copying File c:\testHere2\george fn.rbxl
The operation completed successfully.
2021/08/14 08:39:32 ERROR 0 (0x00000000) Copying File c:\testHere2\Jorge Antonio's Notebook.url
The operation completed successfully.
```

For some reason it is failing to copy these files (it copies them empty), however, it copies them when I run the command from an admin Windows PowerShell inside Windows.

I guess the line on top indicates a permissions issue?

Anyone could help clarify what kind of folder this is and why `robocopy` fails from CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might a rights issue as in an Windows environment. There is still a system rights category above admin rights.
Try to take ownership of the files and set rights accordingly.

Furthermore the files in questions could either be unreadable (broken storage) or an antivirus program prevents robocopy from accessing them.

Comment: You seemed to be right, I took ownership of the folder and didn’t get anymore errors, then I put the old owner back, and didn't get any errors either.  Still doing more test. I took ownership of the folder and didn’t get anymore errors, then I put the old owner back, and didn't get any errors either.  Thanks!